# usb 3g/4g modem with router - router MAC leak question

Tags: router, network

I have router (dwr-118)  with USB port and usb 4G modem which is connected to this router.

Please tell me if ISP will see ROUTER MAC address or they will see only IMEI from usb 4g modem?

Comment: Please don't post the same question on more than one Stack Exchange site, pick one and remove the question on other sites.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router's MAC addresses are associated with the Ethernet ports - since these are not used with the LTE modem your ISP won't see them.